# How to use ComboBox in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

How to use ComboBox in Xamarin forms because xamarin forms does not have ComboBox Control, In my application i want to show list of country, so that user can select country(search as well as dropdown)both way, Give me suggestion to resolve this issue 
Note:I found one solution syncfusion combobox but that is paid service, i don't want paid service

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/combobox? If yes then you can use the XLabs AutoCompleteView https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/AutoCompleteView.cs

Comment: I am working on it(XLabs), If I have doubt and let you know

Comment: Please note that XLabs is deprecated and has not been maintained for a long time. I would suggest finding an alternative

Comment: @GeraldVersluis i agree its deprecated but whatever is deprecated can easily be converted to the newer versions i believe, please correct me if I am wrong sir!

Answer (score 11):

Xamarin Forms does include a combo box control, it just isn't called a combo box. XF calls it a [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/). It's pretty easy to use and includes properties you can bind to for ItemSource and SelectedItem/SelectedIndex.

Comment: Picker is not recognized as a class in my Xamarin project with VS 2017, which is the library I need to add with using? I can reference all UI elements like ListView, ImageView, CheckBox, but not that element.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource) control at xamarin to achieve list some objects in a box.
I recommend you to follow the MVVM pattern to bind datasource and handle events. There is [code samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/BindablePicker) for it that created by Microsoft.

But basically you have to add a `Picker` to your xaml:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Label Text="Bindable Picker Demo" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Picker Title="Select a country" ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColorName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        
    </StackLayout>
```

And in your model just set your `Countrylist` property and It is selected item.

```
public IList<string> CountryList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> {"USA","Germany","England"};
        }
    }
```

If you want to make search in your `Picker` you have to create your own [control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view). According your wishes an [`Entry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry) and a [`Listview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) may be enough. You have to update your list in `TextChanged` event of Entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `ListView` with `ItemsSource` as a country list, and `SearchView` with `TextChanged` method, where you change your `ItemsSource` by search value (and firstly, ItemsSource would be empty, because of empty search filter).

Also you can check [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15170/filtering-listview-with-searchview), that could be also useful.

**UPDATE:**

If you need a searchable Picker, there is a github project, that you can use. It has a search. [Link to project](https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls).

Comment: Is it possible to achieve ComboBox in Xamarin Forms because we are developing app using xamarin forms in visual studio 2017

Comment: @P.Thiyagu I've updated my answer, found project for you.

Comment: Thank you all, I am going to use Xfx Controls

Comment: @P.Thiyagu you are welcome! You can upvote and choose as accepted to show other users what answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Picker Control is useful for creating Combo Box**

**Step1:** Follow First Criteria for Layout Control in **.xaml** File

```
<StackLayout>
    
    <Picker Title="Placeholder" BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="liname"></Picker>
    
</StackLayout>
```

**Step2:** Now Add the the Values in **.xaml.cs** File

```
    public yourcode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        liname.Items.Add("class1");
        liname.Items.Add("class2");
        liname.Items.Add("class3");
        liname.Items.Add("class4");

    }
```

Now Start the  Emulator in Vs, See the Output Screen Below of my Code

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution guys. I am using picker instead of combo box, There is no combo box option in xamarin forms, If you want exact combo box, need to subscribe syncfusion